# Angular2 promise to http observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am having an issue switching from a promise to an http observable in Angular2. 
I have 2 methods getEmployees() and getEmployee(id:number).

I was able to successfully switch the getEmployees() however I am getting various error messages(filter doesn't exist on type observable) when trying to switch the getEmployee(id:number)

Original - Service.ts

```
getEmployee(id: number) {
    return Promise.resolve(EMPLOYEES).then(
        employees => employees.filter(employee => employee.id === id)[0]
    );
```

1st try service.ts

```
getEmployee(id: number) {
        return this.http.get(employeesUrl + id).map(employee => employee.id === id)[0]
    );
```

Original - Component.ts

```
    let id = +curr.getParam('id');
    this.employeeService.getEmployee(id).then(employee => {
        this.employee = employee;
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`http.get()` returns a observable of [Response](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/Response-class.html) object. You need to get the data from it, usually by calling it's `json()` method. Then you can apply transformations to your data - map, filter etc.

```
getEmployee(id: number) {
  return this.http.get(employeesUrl + id)
    .map(response => response.json())
    .map(employee => employee.id === id)[0]
);
```

Observable this service returns is **cold** - it won't do anything until you explicitly ask by subscribing to it in your component:

```
let id = +curr.getParam('id');
this.employeeService.getEmployee(id).subscribe(employee => {
  this.employee = employee;
});
```

Comment: oh damn, i forgot about the .json part haha, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return an observable to subscribe to:

This returns an observable that is going to be mapped to employees with id equals to the id passed.

```
getEmployee(id: number) {
  return this.http.get(employeesUrl + id).map(res => res.json()).map(employee => employee.id === id);
);
```

Then, you can subscribe to it like this, and the first call back of the subscription is the `next` or `successful` callback:

```
let id = +curr.getParam('id');
this.employeeService.getEmployee(id).subscribe(employees => {
  maybe this.employee = employees[0];
});
```

Second callback is `error`, third callback is `complete`.

FYI, didnt test it but its basically the idea behind observables.

Edit: @Sasxa made me realize i was missing a really big step haha.